# How to hide blank array and just leave array's value/name?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete plugin. How to hide blank array and just leave array's value/name? For example

Html :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        $("#ac5").autocomplete('search.php', {
            minChars: 1,

        });

       });

        </script>
    <form>
            <input type="text" id="ac5">
        </form>
```

Php :

```
/*
 * Load sample data
 */

$dir    = '../image/imagefiles/';
$images = scandir($dir);




/*
 * Results array
 */
$results = $images;

/*
 * Autocomplete formatter
 */
function autocomplete_format($results) {
    foreach ($results as $result) { 
        echo $result;
    }
}

/*
 * Output format
 */
$output = 'autocomplete';
if (isset($_GET['output'])) {
    $output = strtolower($_GET['output']);
}

/*
 * Output results
 */
if ($output === 'json') {
    echo json_encode($results);
} else {
    echo autocomplete_format($results);
}
```

Output of autocomplete :     `...Dj_Etrom_Remix1.jpgDj_Etrom_Remix2.jpgDj_Etrom_Remix3.jpg` it show me all files name in same line  but i want to do like this `Dj Etrom Remix.jpg`.

Comment: your line `$data = array(print_r($images) );` is strange... print_r makes a string, so I don't believe it makes an array... Why don't you directly use `$images` instead of `print_r($images)` ?

Comment: remove `$data = array( print_r($images) );` and change `$results = $data;` to `$results = $images;` line and see what happens

Comment: Working but it show the values in same line. @Viral

Comment: what do you mean by "in same line" ? can you add the output of "print_r($images)" in your question, to see the structure of your data ?

Comment: also mention your desired output if type is not `json`.

Comment: I remove `$data = array( print_r($images) );` and change  `$results = $data;` to `$results = $images;` but Output of autocomplete   `...Dj_Etrom_Remix1.jpgDj_Etrom_Remix2.jpgDj_Etrom_Remix3.jpg`  show me in same line i mean all files name in same line.

Comment: Please see the update above. @Random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is `your autocomplete_format` function, that simply `echo` each element of the array...

You can do whatever you want to in it.
If you want all file in a new line, use `echo $result."\n";`, 
if you wish it in html page, use `echo $result."<br/>";`,
if you want to separate them with a comma, use `echo $result.", ";`...

But with jQuery autocomplete, you should send it as json array...

Comment: Thank you so much wokred with `echo $result."\n";` .